# Contact Form 7 mail tags were not correct. Emails lost?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I just learned that the mail templates/tags were not correct and we received emails with [your-message].

I'm not optimistic about this, but still, is there any possibility to get the mail body?

Comment: If you're not storing the mail body anywhere on the server, either in WordPress, or the mail logs, then no.

Answer (score 0):

The mail-tags that you have given while creating the contact-form should be the same as what you have written in the message body. You can check it in the mail option.
if you want to know more contact me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).